# Oracle regexp_like getting wrong results

Tags: oracle11g

I have this like select and its working fine:

```
select * from printers where 
         printer_id like 'XERX-15%' Or printer_id like 'OFFJT-16%' ;
```

I am trying to convert the expression to regexp_like because I have many of these like conditions,

```
select * from printers where
    regexp_like(printer_id,'XERX-15%|OFFJT-16%')
```

seems like its giving wrong results...

```
create table printers(printer_id varchar(50));
insert into printers values('XERX-1500');
insert into printers values('XERX-1550');
insert into printers values('XERX-1560');
insert into printers values('XERX-1570');
insert into printers values('XERX-1601');
insert into printers values('XERX-1601');
insert into printers values('XERX-1602');
insert into printers values('XERX-1603');
insert into printers values('OFFJT-1504');
insert into printers values('OFFJT-1604');
```

select * from printers where
printer_id like 'XERX-15%' Or printer_id like 'OFFJT-16%' ;

select * from printers where
regexp_like(printer_id,'XERX-15%|OFFJT-16%')

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44c23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is not a wild-card in regular expressions.

You want:

```sql
select *
from   printers
where  regexp_like(printer_id,'^(XERX-15|OFFJT-16)')
```

- `^` matches the start of the string then
- either `XERX-15` or `OFFJT-16`.

If you don't want to use a capturing group `()` then you could equivalently use:

```sql
select *
from   printers
where  regexp_like(printer_id,'^XERX-15|^OFFJT-16')
```

Answer (score 2):

The % symbol is a `like` wildcard. In your regex it's a literal character; so remove it:

```
regexp_like(printer_id,'XERX-15|OFFJT-16')
```

Or to only match at the start of the line (as your original does):

```
regexp_like(printer_id,'^(XERX-15|OFFJT-16)')
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44c23/8)